# How do you do a mysql join where the join may come from one or another table

Tags: mysql, join

This is the query that I am using to match up a members name to an id.

```
SELECT eve_member_list.`characterID` ,eve_member_list.`name` 
FROM `eve_mining_op_members`
INNER JOIN eve_member_list ON eve_mining_op_members.characterID = eve_member_list.characterID
WHERE op_id = '20110821105414-741653460';
```

My issue is that I have two different member lists, one lists are members that belong to our group and the second list is a list of members that do not belong to our group.

How do i write this query so that if a member is not found in the `eve_member_list` table it will look in the `eve_nonmember_member_list` table to match the `eve_mining_op_members.characterID` to the `charName`

I apologize in advance if the question is hard to read as I am not quite sure how to properly ask what it is that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` and join with both the tables. Use `IFNULL` to select the name if it appears in the first table, but if it is `NULL` (because no match was found) then it will use the value found from the second table.

```
SELECT
    characterID,
    IFNULL(eve_member_list.name, eve_nonmember_member_list.charName) AS name
FROM eve_mining_op_members
LEFT JOIN eve_member_list USING (characterID)
LEFT JOIN eve_nonmember_member_list USING (characterID)
WHERE op_id = '20110821105414-741653460';
```

If you have control of the database design you should also consider if it is possible to redesign your database so that both members and non-members are stored in the same table. You could for example use a boolean to specify whether or not they are members. Or you could create a `person` table and have information that is only relevant to members stored in a separate `memberinfo` table with an nullable foreign key from the `person` table to the `memberinfo` table. This will make queries relating to both members and non-members easier to write and perform better.

Comment: this is close but does not return the characterID of the members that do not belong to the `eve_member_list` table.  It does, how ever, return the names correctly

Comment: @Wes: I fixed it. See update. I think this method will give better performance than the approach you have accepted.

Comment: Yes, this also worked like a charm.  I hate to move an accepted answer but I do agree this is probably a better solution.  Thank you.

Comment: @Mark - better performance perhaps but by using a LEFT JOIN, the amount of records returned might differ from what OP expects. otoh, it might be safe to assume that a characterID will always be in either the member or nonmember list.

Comment: Yes, the two tables are laid out the same.  I know this is bad db design as I could do as another poster said and just set a bool value that lets me know which group the member belongs to and combine the two tables, but I wanted to get an understanding on how to accomplish this type of solution as it will likely come up in the future in other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options but by

- using a `UNION` between the `eve_member_list` and `eve_nonmember_member_list` table
- and `JOIN` the results of this `UNION` with your original `eve_mining_op_members` table

you will get your required results.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  lst.`characterID` 
        , lst.`name` 
FROM    `eve_mining_op_members` AS m
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  characterID
                  , name
          FROM    eve_member_list
          UNION ALL                  
          SELECT  characterID
                  , name
          FROM    eve_nonmember_member_list
        ) AS lst ON lst.characterID = m.characterID
WHERE op_id = '20110821105414-741653460';
```

Comment: worked like a charm other than the table name is `eve_nonmember_member_list` rather than `eve_nonmember_list`.. I know horrible name, I couldn't think of a good way to describe it.... to many hours behind the keys.

Comment: I have switched the accepted answer to Mark Byers answer as I think it is a little easier to read and looks as though it would give more performance.  If either of you can give me evidence other wise I will gladly switch.  At this point I am marking for other readers as both of your solutions work.

Comment: @Wes - I have added a comment when the LEFT JOIN solution might give unexpected results but I think it is safe to assume that doesn't apply to your situation. If you measured both queries yourself for speed, got the same results and found Mark's solution performing better, by all means, use that.

Comment: I read this and it is a very good point.  In my situation it does not apply but if i could give you another +1 for the potential that it will help other members I would.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a left join on both tables, and then selecting the non-null results from the resulting query -

```
select * from
(select * from
  eve_mining_op_members as x
  left join eve_member_list  as y1 on x.characterID = y1.characterID
  left join eve_member_list2 as y2 on x.characterID = y2.characterID) as t
where t.name is not null
```

Or, you could try the same thing with a union and using inner join (assuming joined tables are the same):

```
select * from
(select * from eve_mining_op_members as x
 inner join eve_member_list  as y1 on x.characterID = y1.characterID
  UNION
 select * from eve_mining_op_members as x
 inner join eve_member_list2 as y2 on x.characterID = y2.characterID) as t
```

You can throw in your `op_id` condition where you see fit (sorry, I didn't really understand where it came from). Good luck!

Comment: these throw an error as eve_member_list2 does not exist, I am assuming you want me to put in replace of this the name of the second table? The `op_id` is the group in which both lists of members can belong to.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you named your other table (either missed it or its not there).

Comment: I apologize, it was far from the best question I have asked on here.   It was there but was not very clear.